# IllegalStateException: Fragment already added; unable to figure out exact reason and location from fabric log

Tags: android, google-fabric

I am getting following log from crashlytics tool google fabric which shows why application is crashing in production environment.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: ProductsFragment{1e716898 #1 id=0x7f0a11fb android:switcher:2131366395:0}
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1891)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:760)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2215)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2190)
   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8472)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2400)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2093)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2369)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1719)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2786)
   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8667)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4558)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4425)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3937)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3990)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3956)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4073)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3964)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4130)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3937)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3990)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3956)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3964)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3937)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6269)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6219)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6190)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6359)
   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

Me and my team is trying to reproduce this crash but unable to do it nor we can figure out where exactly application is crashing as line number or activity name is not mentioned in logs. we are using ProductsFragment on many screens.

Can anyone help me with this problem.

Comment: Do you want us to guess or something?

Comment: lol, Actually I am asking is there is know issue in ViewPager or any other android component which causes this behavior. App is working fine but still getting this issue in crashlytics.

Comment: Please show a sample code of how you add your fragment

Comment: @DCoder did you find a solution or a hint ? My team and I are also facing this crash. W're unable to reproduce or get more info from the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

This is a frustrating error to get in production. I have had the same in the past.

How are you adding the fragment? Are using 'add' or 'replace' with fragment manager?

You could always see if a fragment exists in the stack:

```
 YourFrag f = (YourFrag) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("MY_AWESOME_FRAG");

 if (f != null) {
     fm.beginTransaction()
       .replace(R.id.bottomContainer, f, "MY_AWESOME_FRAG")
       .commit();
 } else {
      fm.beginTransaction()
       .add(R.id.bottomContainer, f, "MY_AWESOME_FRAG")
       .commit();
 }
```

Comment: I think the `.add()` method will have an issue since `f` is null when hitting the else clause